# How to extract a string between the first two and last two characters in java?

Tags: java, regex

**Edited:** I want to extract the string between two special characters at the beginning and end.

Input can be one of the following:
`{[TestString]}`
`{TestString}`
`[TestString]`
`[TestString]}`
`{[TestString`

Expected Output: `TestString`

Here the special characters `{`, `[`, `]`, `}` are optional.  The input string can be with/without these special chars at the beginning and end.

Using this regex below in `Pattern.compile()`, I am not getting the intended result.

`(?=\[|\{)(.*?)(?=\]|\})`

Comment: What do you mean with optional? Can you have `[TestString`, `Teststring]`, `{[Teststring]`, `{Teststring]`, etc.?

Comment: "*Here the special characters `{`, `[`, `]`, `}` are optional.*" Your pattern seems to require them, can you ensure you've used the term "optional" as you've intended?

Comment: Are these string embedded in longer strings where you need to pull them from?

Comment: @JvdV Yes those are valid inputs too.

Comment: @Harish, please provide those type of sample data too in your OP.

Comment: @JvdV, updated my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used a lookahead assertion where you should have used lookbehind. Character classes make sure that either of `[{` and `]}` will match:

```
(?<=[{\[])(.*?)(?=[]}])
```

This would return `TestString`

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/TMBEvW/2). Be aware that you need to double the backslashes if you want to build the regex using a Java String (check the Code Generator feature of Regex101).

Comment: When the input string is `{TestString]}` (note the '[' missing), I get "Your regular expression does not match the subject string."

Comment: This was not clear from your original question. I have updated my answer

Comment: Thank you very much!  I got two excellent answers to my question, both works. I accepted your solution to mention java's requirement of double slashes for regex and code generator utility - something I wasn't aware of before.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex:

```sh
[\[{]*([^\]\[{}]+)[]}]*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5qFWc6/3/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `[\[{]*`: Match 0 or more of `[` or `{` characters
- `([^\]\[{}]+)`: Match 1 or more of any characters that are not `[`, `]`, `{` and `}`. Capture this in group #1
- `[]}]*`: Match 0 or more of `]` or `}` characters

**Demo using Java:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Test
        
        Stream.of(
                "{[TestString]}", 
                "{TestString}", 
                "[TestString]", 
                "[TestString]}", 
                "{[TestString"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + " => " + getToken(s)));       
    }
    static String getToken(String s) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[\\[{]*([^\\]\\[{}]+)[]}]*").matcher(s);
        String token="";
        if(matcher.find()) {
            token = matcher.group(1);
        }
        return token;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{[TestString]} => TestString
{TestString} => TestString
[TestString] => TestString
[TestString]} => TestString
{[TestString => TestString
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like `^\{?\[?(.*?)\]?\}?$`, that is

```
(?x) # enable comments  - just for this description
^    # start
\{?  # optional {
\[?  # optional [
(    # start group
.*?  # anything reluctant (try as less as possible)
)    # group end
\]?  # optional ]
\}?  # optional }
$    # end
```

see [regexplanet](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyd9xpdnr) <sub>press the green Java field to see it running</sub>